# Как правильно создать поток в Qt

Tags: c++, qt, многопоточность, qthread, worker-threads

Для теста, я начал реализовывать самый примитивный `worker`, который будет помещен в `QThread`, и тут же столкнулся с проблемой, а именно с данной ошибкой:

> QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication

Я хочу реализовать самый простой способ запуска потока с помощью `worker-а`. Код выглядит так:

---

**`worker.h`**

```cpp
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit Worker(QObject* parrent = nullptr);
    Worker &operator=(const Worker &other) = delete;
    Worker &operator=(Worker &&other)      = delete;
    Worker(const Worker &other)            = delete;
    Worker(Worker &&other)                 = delete;
    virtual ~Worker()                      = default;

public slots:

    virtual void start();
    virtual void stop ();

signals:

    void started();
    void stopped();

};
```

**`worker.cpp`**

```cpp
Worker::Worker(QObject* parrent) : QObject(parrent)
{
}

void Worker::start()
{
    qDebug() << "Worker started";
    emit started();
}

void Worker::stop ()
{
    qDebug() << "Worker stopped";
    emit stopped();
}
```

**`mytask.h`**

```cpp
class MyTask : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit MyTask(QObject* parrent = nullptr);
    MyTask& operator=(const MyTask& other) = delete;
    MyTask& operator=(MyTask&& other)      = delete;
    MyTask(const MyTask& other)            = delete;
    MyTask(MyTask&& other)                 = delete;
    virtual ~MyTask()                      = default;

    virtual void start();
    virtual void stop ();

signals:

    void started();
    void stopped();

protected:

    Worker* p_worker{ nullptr };

};
```

**`mytask.cpp`**

```cpp
MyTask::MyTask(QObject* parrent) : QObject(parrent), p_worker(nullptr)
{
}

void MyTask::stop()
{
    if (p_worker) {
        p_worker->stop();
    }
}

void MyTask::start()
{
    p_worker        = new Worker();
    QThread* thread = new QThread();
    p_worker->moveToThread(thread);
    
    connect(this, &MyTask::started, this, [](){qDebug() << "MyTask started";});
    connect(this, &MyTask::stopped, this, [](){qDebug() << "MyTask stopped";});
    
    connect(thread,   &QThread::started,  p_worker, &Worker::start,            Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(p_worker, &Worker::started,   this,     [this](){emit started();}, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(p_worker, &Worker::stopped,   this,     [this](){emit stopped();}, Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(p_worker, &Worker::stopped,   thread,   &QThread::quit,            Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(p_worker, &Worker::stopped,   p_worker, &Worker::deleteLater,      Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(thread,   &QThread::finished, thread,   &QThread::deleteLater,     Qt::DirectConnection);
    
    thread->start();
}
```

---

**Важно** отметить то, что мне нужна реализация именно с использованием `worker-a`. При создании `worker-a`, я буду работать с ним при помощи сигналов. Стоит также отметить, что в этом примере все проверки на устранение повторного запуска потока и так далее игнорируются (для демонстрации упращеного кода).

Данный пример должен был бы вывести мне в качестве результата вот такое последование сообщений:

```bsh
Worker started
MyTask started
Worker stopped
MyTask stopped
```

но я получаю:

```bsh
Worker started
QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication
Worker stopped
MyTask stopped
```

**UPD** Код запуска программы:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    MyTask task;
    task.start();
    QThread::sleep(1);
    task.stop();
    QThread::sleep(1);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Так это. А `QApplication`, на который оно жалуется, есть?

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, нет, но он и не нужен. Он предназначен для GUI.

Comment: Ну вам сообщение об ошибке недвусмысленно намекает на то, что нужен цикл обработки событий, для которого нужен `QApplication` (на самом деле достаточно `QCoreApplication` емнип)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, спасибо большое - помогло. Я честно говоря, забыл про его существование. Но при запуске программы, я все же не получаю сообщение от сигнала `MyTask::started`

Comment: покажите код запуска. скорее всего где-то сигнал не дошел из-за того, что цикл обработки событий запустился позже

Comment: @BeardedBeaver добавил в конце вопроса.

Comment: @bbdd `QThread::sleep()` замени на `QTimer::singleShot()` пока `QEventLoop` не запустится сигналы из потока не будут приходить... а ещё мне `emit` в лямбде не нравится...

Comment: @Fat-Zer не думаю, что `emit` в лямбде приведет к каким-то ошибкам. Интересное наблюдение, что после вызова `emit-a` в лямбде таким вот способом - `this->emit started(); и тд.`, последовательность отпечатывания сигналов поменялось, а именно: 
`Worker started; Worker stopped;  MyTask::stopped; MyTask::started`. Не могу понять, почему сообщение `MyTask::started` стало последним, хотя что должно быть 2, после `Worker::started`.

Comment: Сделал отдельные слоты для вызова сигналов `started` и `stopped` у класса `MyTask` и все заработало. Но все же, не могу понять, почему при вызове сигнала в лямбде, происходит непонятное поведение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам следует разобраться с тем как в Qt работают сигналы и слоты. Я писал когда-то статью "правильная работа с потоками в Qt" на Хабре, Вы ее легко найдете поиском.

Если говорить коротко, то для корректной работы многих сигналов и слотов Вам нужен запущенный event loop. Идея в том что когда у Вас два потока пытаются посылать сигналы друг другу, то чтобы это работало в реальности каждый из них поддерживает специальную очередь для сообщений и крутит цикл который регулярно проверяет появление в этой очереди сообщений. Это и есть event loop. Он по умолчанию создается у каждого QThread, но есть и еще один специальный event loop для всего приложения. Там живут обработчики все QObject у которых нет явно назначенного отдельного QThread (в том числе сами объекты QThread) и там обрабатываются сообщения от операционной системы. Например если Вы попытаетесь закрыть программу до того как она завершится сама, то это событие будет обработано именно там. И когда Ваши два потока завершатся, то именно этот цикл должен будет решить что пора завершать программу самостоятельно. Вот эти все connect между Worker::stopped и Worker::deleteLater - все это обрабатывается там.

Для запуска этого системного event loop (ну и подобных технических вещей) в Qt есть специальный класс QApplication и его специализации. Вам нужен, как уже заметили, минималистический QCoreApplication. А собственно запуск цикла у этого класса - это вызов функции .exec(). Который у Вас происходит *после* того как Вы попытались запустить event loop в QThread. Вполне закономерно что Вы получаете сообщения об ошибках - первый поток стартует еще до того как запустился системный event loop.

Как это поправить? Один из способов - запускать Ваши потоки не явным вызовом .start() а через отправку события. Эта функция не просто так сделана слотом. Последовательность действий должна быть такова:

1. Вы создаете QApplication (всегда это должно быть одно из первых действий программы до создания любых QObject). Это создает в числе прочего системный event loop и позволяет помещать туда события
2. Создаете свой начальный набор событий, потоков и т.п. Отправляете им событие "запустись". Оно будет помещено в очередь QApplication но реально не отправлено, т.к. event loop еще не запущен
3. Зовете app.exec(). Event loop запускается и рассылает Ваши сообщения получателям, у Вас запускаются потоки и все работает

Но вообще исходя из Вашей задачи, мне кажется что Вам стоит присмотреться к QConcurrent. Грубо говоря вызывать QtConcurrent::run. Как вариант - использовать QThreadPool + QRunnable. Без использования QObject, сигналов и слотов. Тогда Вам будет не нужно QApplication и логика в целом скорее всего сильно упростится.

Comment: Большое спасибо за хороший ответ. Я прочитал Вашу статью, и вынес много полезного. Но у меня появился вопрос, связанный с созданием класса, унаследованного от `QRunnable`. Если я хочу избавиться от `Worker-a` и реализовать всю логику в одном классе, то при унаследовании `QRunnable`, я должен реализовать `run` метод. Окей, не проблема. Но могу ли я в методе `start`, запустить метод `run` в новом треде, благодаря `QThreadPool`, а именно:  `QThreadPool::globalInstance()->start(this);`

Comment: Да, вполне можете. ->start() запустит Ваш код в отдельном потоке. Обратите только внимание что по умолчанию ->start() берет на себя владение переданным ему QRunnable и попытается в конце его самостоятельно удалить. Соответственно либо убедитесь что Ваш объект не попытается удалить кто-то другой (в частности не создавайте его на стеке) либо сделайте ему setAutoDelete(false) до start()

Comment: `setAutoDelete(false)` больше по душе. Большое спасибо за помощь.